# In Firebase auth, can I store info about a user in my own properties?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Using firebase auth, it'd be very convenient to store some info about a user. I'm aware of storing info on `firebase.auth().currentUser` like `email` & `displayName`. Is there a way I can make my own property and store info on the user I want to? I have tried manually adding a property but it doesn't persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Auth was not designed to store arbitrary user data.  You're supposed to use a database for that, and link that data to the user account via its UID.  The choice of database is completely up to you, but it's common to use Realtime Database or Firestore, since you can also use security rules to restrict access to just that user

See also:

- [Firebase: should I store user data on the authentication profile or database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817428/firebase-should-i-store-user-data-on-the-authentication-profile-or-database)
- [Save data into the Firebase user object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60704394/save-data-into-the-firebase-user-object)
- [How do I link each user to their data in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910704/how-do-i-link-each-user-to-their-data-in-firebase)
- [How to store user data using Firebase in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682633/how-to-store-user-data-using-firebase-in-android)